# Change default columns displayed in search results in Thunderbird 3

Tags: macos, thunderbird

How can I add the "Location" column to permanently appear in search results?

I am running TB 3.1.10 on Mac Os X 10.6.6.

Answer (score 2):

There are two options that I know of.

A) Use the [Mnenhy Addon](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/addon/mnenhy/). This will solve this problem and also offers many other features.

B) Or follow the steps to this workaround:

1. Perform a search from Edit>Find>Search Messages (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>)
2. Click on Save as Search Folder and choose which folders to search to mimic a global search
3. Arrange columns in the search folder as desired

When you want to perform a search, just do: Right-Click>Properties, enter a search criterion, and update.  The results will be displayed in this folder with the same columns as everywhere else. It's not the most elegant, but that's why it's a workaround.